# katexR not rendering in rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, katex

When trying to knit katexR in an Rmd documment, I get the following error:

```
pandoc: Could not fetch /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/katexR/htmlwidgets/lib/katex/fonts/KaTeX_AMS-Regular.woff2
```

Any ideas of why that might be?

````
```{r}
# devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/katexR")
library(katexR)
katex("\\KaTeX")
```
````

Comment: Do you really want to re-download and install the package every time you compile the document?

Comment: Comment out `devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/katexR")` this if you already installed the package

Comment: I do have the same issue... I have `KaTeX_AMS-Regular.woff` in the `katexR/htmlwidgets/lib/katex/fonts` directory, but no `.woff2` fonts.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been on StackOverflow in a while.  I below it is simple, but let me confirm.  The issue is pandoc does not recognize woff2, so we have to delete it in htmlwidgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone out there is still listening, please try reinstalling with

```
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/katexR")
```

For reference, see the discussion in [this Github issue](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/katexR/issues/4).  My test to see if it works was to knit the vignette.

I would love feedback.  Thanks.

Comment: great, and now that I have semi-automated, the next update should be smooth and easy.  would love additional feedback and examples with `katexR`.  glad you are using it.